# Cassandra: Geo Redundancy and consistency

Tags: cassandra, high-availability, consistency, cap-theorem

Consider a Cassandra instance deployed across two data centers for geo-redundancy.

Is it possible configure this cluster with a consistency level such that we get both Geo-redundancy (availablity even if one of the entire data-center takes a downtime and the instance continues to operate with one data center) and full consistent read and write. Does this ask violate the CAP theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't (otherwise you'd violate CAP).

If you want fully consistent read/writes *across* data centers then you will have to give up availability or partition tolerance.